# Can I run a pull DTS package on SQL 2000 to copy data from SQL 2005 (compatibility level 90) to SQL 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

Can we still run our DTS package on SQL 2000 to pull data from a SQL 2005 database with **compatibility level** set to "SQL Server 2005 (90)" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

That said, there were some new datatypes introduced in 2005 (off the top of my head, XML and VARCHAR(MAX), plus user defined types) - so you'll have to look out for those as they would cause a problem.